# Get Post time in Magento Fishpig

Tags: wordpress, date, magento, post, fishpig

How can I display the time of WordPress post (Eg: 1 Day Ago) in Magento fishpig?

```
<?php $posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <div class="block block-blog block-recent-posts">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getTitle()): ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></span></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <ul id="<?php echo $this->getListId() ?>">
            <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($post->getPostTitle()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($post->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('<?php echo $this->getListId() ?>')</script>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date of a post you would need to do in your foreach loop:

```php
<?php echo $post->getPostDate() ?>
```

If you want the difference between now and the postdate, i. e. *1 day ago* you probably have to write your own function. Wordpress has its own function [human_time_diff](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff) for that which does not exist in Magento.

Comment: This is correct. You can also pass the date format to the method: <?php echo $post->getPostDate('Ymd') ?>. To get a human time difference, you would need to code this yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to convert date format like this 2016-07-27T00:43:11+00:00

Answer (score -1):

For Human Time Difference Use:

```
function get_date_diff( $time1, $time2, $precision = 2 ) {
// If not numeric then convert timestamps
if( !is_int( $time1 ) ) {
    $time1 = strtotime( $time1 );
}
if( !is_int( $time2 ) ) {
    $time2 = strtotime( $time2 );
}
// If time1 > time2 then swap the 2 values
if( $time1 > $time2 ) {
    list( $time1, $time2 ) = array( $time2, $time1 );
}
// Set up intervals and diffs arrays
$intervals = array( 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second' );
$diffs = array();
foreach( $intervals as $interval ) {
    // Create temp time from time1 and interval
    $ttime = strtotime( '+1 ' . $interval, $time1 );
    // Set initial values
    $add = 1;
    $looped = 0;
    // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
    while ( $time2 >= $ttime ) {
        // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
        $add++;
        $ttime = strtotime( "+" . $add . " " . $interval, $time1 );
        $looped++;
    }
    $time1 = strtotime( "+" . $looped . " " . $interval, $time1 );
    $diffs[ $interval ] = $looped;
}
$count = 0;
$times = array();
foreach( $diffs as $interval => $value ) {
    // Break if we have needed precission
    if( $count >= $precision ) {
        break;
    }
    // Add value and interval if value is bigger than 0
    if( $value > 0 ) {
        if( $value != 1 ){
            $interval .= "s";
        }
        // Add value and interval to times array
        $times[] = $value . " " . $interval;
        $count++;
    }
}
// Return string with times
return implode( ", ", $times );
}
```

> **To print Timestamp(POST) :** $t1 = $post->getPostDate(c);
>
> **To print Timestamp(Current Time)** : $t2 = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('c');

**USAGE:**

> var_dump( get_date_diff( $t, $t2, 1 ) ); // string '1 month'(length=7)
>
> var_dump( get_date_diff( $t, $t2, 2 ) ); // string '1 month, 4 days' (length=15)
>
> var_dump( get_date_diff( $t, $t2, 3 ) ); //string '1 month, 4 days, 5 hours' (length=24)